# Finding a two-distance set

Tags: geometry

How can I find a two-distance set $X$ in $\mathbb R^n$ containing $n(n-1)/2$ points? It might be a typo and it might should have been $n(n+1)/2$ points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it is a typo or not, but to find a two-distance set with $\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ points is a standard exercise. To construct the set consider all points with two coordinates equal to $1$ and the other $n-2$ coordinates equal to $0.$ Check that this is a two-distance set and that the number of elements on it is $\binom{n}{2}.$